# How can we merge a video and audio file in windows 8 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am working on a windows 8 app and I have to merge a video file that can be in .mp4 or any other format and an audio file that is .mp3 file and in output I need a .mp4 video file.
How can we Implement it in Windows 8 using c# or is there any dll file we can use.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can get you started?

Microsoft Media Foundation.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms694197.aspx

An example is shown here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eternalcoding/archive/2013/03/06/developing-a-winrt-component-to-create-a-video-file-using-media-foundation.aspx